# How to save an image at its original resolution? On iPad 6th gen

Tags: ipad, resolution

All photos saved to the Photos app seem to be a slightly lowered resolution from the original image, I believe it’s one of the main reasons reposts progressively lose more and more pixels. Is there any way whatsoever to avoid this? When I want an image, I want *that image*, not a slightly worse version of it.

I did see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63896/how-to-view-high-res-images-in-ipad-3-without-downsampling), but the suggested solution, using save image, doesn’t seem to fix the issue. On iPadOS 13.6

It’s also worth noting you can’t even use save image in Line Webtoon.

Also, I pretty much always save images from Google Chrome, does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Are you referring to the 'Optimize iPad Storage' setting for Photos?

Comment: No, I know what that does and this is separate from that. I double checked that the lowered resolution images weren’t just mostly on the cloud by pressing the edit button and making them download. It is a feature that I know about, and have on deliberately.

What I am referring to is different.